# Moving a div to another position, but only if it is contained in another div?

Tags: css, positioning

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="someclass">
    ....
</div>
```

How can I say that the div should only be moved, if any of the parent divs hass class XYZ?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "moved" please. Draggable by the user? Moved with javascript?

Comment: Move = change the position on the page.

Comment: Only parent or ancestors as well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the element based on its parent/ancestor:

```
/* the 'default' */
.someclass {
    position: relative;
}

/* the someclass element that has an ancestor of class 'ancestorClass' */
.ancestorClass .someclass {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Without clear (or any) information as regards what 'moving' means, in context, I'm assuming that you're using `position` to reposition the element in some manner. If you're taking another approach, then simply amend the CSS rules to reflect your needs.

Comment: In which case I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this ?

```
.XYZ > .someclass  /* use this if the .someclass is next child class of the .XYZ */
{
   position:absolute; /* relative or fixed */  
}
```

or simply use as David Thomas did

```
.XYZ .someclass   /* use this if the .someclass is a child class or inside to .XYZ  */
{
  position:absolute; /* relative or fixed */  
}
```

Comment: I don't *think* he does; the inference I drew from the [slightly corrected] sentence "if any of the parent divs [have] class XYZ" is that the `XYZ` element could be the parent or any other ancestor.

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks I edited it. I am not good in english maybe there are some grammatical errors :)